# Scripts cannot make reference to roscpp or rospy

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are using ROS kinetic on a HP elitedesk 800 G2 mini (I7-6700T). Catkin doesn't work when we use any ROS functions in one of the scripts. For example for using the Joy package with a joystick it gives the following error (same error for every statement in the script):

```
CMakeFiles/joy_node.dir/src/joy_node.cpp.o: In function `main':
joy_node.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
```

When using the same scripts on other computers (with same ROS version) it works fine. What could be our problem? Can this be a Linux problem? We already tried to make a new workspace, reinstall ROS and adapting the CmakeList.txt according to some other questions asked on this forum.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273587/scripts-cannot-make-reference-to-roscpp-or-rospy/) by [lsrp1](https://answers.ros.org/users/32328/lsrp1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
This is a linker error, so I suspect you're not linking to the proper libraries.

Can you show us your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Also: what distribution is this? Are you building ROS from source?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
re: `rospy`: I'm not sure I follow. That is a Python library, so there is no linking there (at least not in the way a compiled language does/need it). If you have errors specifically related to `rospy`, please add those as well.

At most you could get `cannot import ..` errors I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hallo, the problem has been solved by re-reinstalling ubuntu to generic version. I had the low latancy version, which ddoesn't seem to work with ros.

---

Originally posted by [lsrp1](https://answers.ros.org/users/32328/lsrp1/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
I'm not saying it didn't work for you, but that seems a bit strange to me. With "low latency version", are you referring to the `low-latency` kernel? That doesn't change your userland, so it would seem strange to me that it would impact something like ROS.

It would be good if you could give ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
.. some more details about what version of Ubuntu you had/have installed, and what you did specifically. That would help future users coming across the same problem much better.